# Implement a relationship between two Spinners in android

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners in my application. I have loaded all the items got from json response. But now I want to implement connection between these 2 Spinners. When select an item in spinner 1 then spinner 2 should load the content according to the spinner 1 selection.

**This is what happens now,**

Spinner 1 loads
1, 2, 3, 4

Spinner 2 loads
1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 4.1, 4.2

But what I want to happen is,

**1st stage**

Spinner 1 loads
1, 2, 3, 4

Spinner 2 loads
Nothing

**2nd stage**

user selecting number 1 in spinner 1 then spinner 2 should load only 1.1, 1.2.

Current Code

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

    try {
        List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

            if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                    && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {

                JSONArray subMenuArray = object
                        .getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                    JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                            .getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
                    crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

                    Log.i("Description",
                            subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                    description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                }

            }
            crustSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_crust);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
            dataAdapterCru
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);

            sizeSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_pizza_size);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, description);
            dataAdapterDes
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what should I do to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

**Latest code**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
                crust = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(crust);
                dataAdapterCru
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);
                crustSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        String crustSelectedItem = crustSP.getSelectedItem()
                                .toString();

                        getFilteredDescriptions(crustSelectedItem, description);

                    }
                });
```

then sending selected crust value

```
List<String> getFilteredDescriptions(String crustSelectedItem,
            List<String> description) {
        List<String> resultDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
        crustSelectedItem = crustSP.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (description == null || description.isEmpty())
            return resultDescription;

        for (int i = 0; i < description.size(); i++) {
            description = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(description);
            if (!description.get(i).contains(crustSelectedItem))
                continue;

            resultDescription.add(description.get(i));

        }

        return resultDescription;

    }
```

Now `resultDescription` has selected crust, respective description values.

this is the place I'm receiving the `resultDescription`

```
sizeSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        resultDescription); //resultDescription cannot be resolved to a variable
                dataAdapterDes
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);
                sizeSP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterDes,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the relationship between two spinners **;)**, follow below steps

1) Have the data in the two lists respectively for **Spinner1** and **Spinner2**.

2) Load first list data into Spinner1.

3) Apply `onItemSelectedListener` listener on Spinner.

4) When user selects item your `onItemSelected` listener 
would be called. you will get the **selected position** and **selected item**.

5) Have a method which can filter out data from list2 based on **selected item** you got in point 4)

6) Set list data which you got in point 4 to Spinner2.

And you have made the relationship.

**Edit** for point 5 I have written below method. pass selected Crust/Value in this method and this will return you Size/Description list for your Spinner2.

```
List<String> getFilteredDescriptions(String crust,List<String> descs){
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(descs == null || descs.isEmpty())
            return result;

        for (int i = 0; i < descs.size(); i++) {
            if(!descs.get(i).contains(crust)) //ignore all descriptions which doesnt have same Crust
                continue;

            result.add(descs.get(i)); // Change

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: nice explanation, can u help me with option 5

Comment: Why don't you add in answer the exact data for both spinners? I will help then

Comment: I have updated the logcat image. crust is 1st spinner and description is 2nd spinner. I have blocked the repetition of same entity (eg: pan). I want load pan in 1st spinner and load pan large and pan medium in 2nd spinner

Comment: Info is incomplete, How do you think you will show only Pan in first spinner and not others? What is the filter here!!

Comment: I have a util class so its calling crust = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(crust);  i mean i have stopped repeating the items. so spinner 1 will load only 4 items and when i select pan then 2nd spinner should display the items according to that

Comment: still i need help, ill add a screen shot for u to get clear idea

Comment: @JohnDavid see my answer it will solve your problem. you need to call that method on onClick of first spinner.
I could suggest better version if you can have a Pizza Object with name and description data. First try above version.

Comment: where should I call this method? inside MyOnItemSelectedListener()? or onTaskCompleted() (I have posted this in question)

Comment: You have to call it in MyOnItemSelectedListener, there you will get your crust name which you have pass in this method along with description array

Comment: result output the value sausage (crust), I want it to output its respective description.

Comment: Add json data in text format, so I can take it and test

Comment: Ok ill add give me sometime, I have one more question. getFilteredDescriptions() returns result; How can I pass it to the 2nd Spinner?

Comment: Seriously? You don't know how to pass parameters!!

Comment: Lol no nothing like that. I know how to do. I'm bit confused because this is a spinner.

Comment: you have to use result list to create adapter instead of using description list.

Comment: Can u check my question, I have added some details. Can u figure what has gone wrong

Comment: Check my answer again, I have made one change it will work now.

Comment: I have updated my question, can u check Edited section n tell me what else i need to do to pass the parameter. (By mistakenly I edited your question)

Comment: its working, wanna know about passing the parameter to the adapter. check edited part in m question. I'm passing resultDescription to dataAdapterDes. I need help to do that

Comment: I am not getting what you are looking for!!

Comment: My problem is getFilteredDescriptions() returns resultDescription; (according to my question edited section). How can I pass it to the 2nd Spinner?

Comment: 1) set onItemClickListener on spinner(the crust one),  
2) and in its onItemClick method get the crust name from Spinner1.
3) Call getFilteredDesc... method pass the required data in it.
4) pass result in adapter,
5) set the adapter in Spinner.

Comment: I have posted it as another question. Can u check it n answer please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824787/passing-a-parameter-to-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

I have to Spinner , one is for to select the department another one is select the executive engineer, when particular department will selected then their associated executive engineers name will be filled on second spinner.

**case_list_selection.xml layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDept"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDept"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Department :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDept"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDept"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:prompt="@string/dept_prompt"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llEE"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llDept"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvExecutiveEngineer"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDept"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Executive Engineer :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerExecutiveEngineer"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDept"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvExecutiveEngineer"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:prompt="@string/exec_prompt" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFromDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFromDate"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" From Date "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg"
                            android:textStyle="bold" 

                 />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFromDate"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint=" From Date "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:enabled="false"

                android:focusable="false"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llToDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="2" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnToDate"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" To Date "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" 


                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtToDate"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnToDate"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint=" To Date "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:enabled="false"
                     android:focusable="false"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#fff"
           >
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00728f"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text=" Search "
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**CaseListSelection.java class**

```
    package com.smartcity;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.city.data.ExceutiveNamesCollection;
    import com.city.webservices.Department_Webservice;
    import com.city.webservices.GetExecutive_Webservices;
    import com.smartcity.R;

    public class CaseListSelection extends Activity{
        Context context;
        Spinner spinnerDept,spinnerExecutiveEngineer;
        ArrayList<ExceutiveNamesCollection> listEE,listExcecutiveNames;
        String executiveNames[];
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        String selectedDept, selectedEE,selectedDeptId,selectedEEId;
        Button btnSearch;
        SimpleDateFormat fmtDateAndTime =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        EditText txtFromDate,txtToDate;
        Calendar myCalendar;
        String fromdate,todate;
        public static int posDept,posEE;
        int pos;
        public String TAG ="CaseListSelection";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            try
            { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.case_list_selection);

            context=this;
            spinnerDept = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDept);

            new Department_Webservice(context,dataAdapter,spinnerDept).execute();

            btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
            spinnerExecutiveEngineer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerExecutiveEngineer);



                    spinnerDept.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            selectedDept = spinnerDept.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            selectedDeptId = Department_Webservice.deptId[position];
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected selectedDeptId : "+selectedDeptId, 2).show();
                            posDept = position;
                            new GetExecutive_Webservices(context,selectedDeptId,dataAdapter,spinnerExecutiveEngineer).execute();

                        }
                    });
                    spinnerExecutiveEngineer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            selectedEE  = spinnerExecutiveEngineer.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            selectedEEId = GetExecutive_Webservices.exceutiveIds[position];
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Selected EE : "+selectedEE, 2).show();
                            pos = position;
                            posEE = position;
                        }
                    });

            Log.v("selectedDeptId", "<<<<<<<<<<<"+selectedDeptId);

            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     fromdate = txtFromDate.getText().toString();
                     todate = txtToDate.getText().toString();
                        Log.v(TAG, "selectedDeptId="+selectedDeptId);
                        Log.v(TAG, "selectedEEId="+selectedEEId);
                        Log.v(TAG, "fromdate="+fromdate);
                        Log.v(TAG, "todate="+todate);



                     Intent i = new Intent(context, CaseList.class);
                        i.putExtra("DeptId", selectedDeptId);
                        i.putExtra("Executive_Id", selectedEEId);
                        i.putExtra("position", pos);

    //              i.putExtra("Dept", selectedDept);
    //              i.putExtra("EE", selectedEE);
                    i.putExtra("FromDate", fromdate);
                    i.putExtra("ToDate", todate);

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }); 


            myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            txtFromDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFromDate);
            txtToDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtToDate);
            Button btnFromDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFromDate);
            btnFromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(context, d, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                } 
            });

            Button btnToDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToDate);
            btnToDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public  void onClick(View v) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(context, todateListener, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        } 
         DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateFromDate();
                } 
                };
                 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener todateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                            int dayOfMonth) {
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateToDate();
                    }
                    };
        private void updateFromDate() {
            txtFromDate.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
        private void updateToDate() {
            txtToDate.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            if (txtFromDate.getText().toString()!=null || txtToDate.getText().toString()!=null)
            {
                try {

                     fromdate = txtFromDate.getText().toString();
                     todate = txtToDate.getText().toString();

                    Date dateFrom = fmtDateAndTime.parse(fromdate); 
                    Date dateTo = fmtDateAndTime.parse(todate); 

                    if (dateTo.before(dateFrom)) 
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "To Date should be greater than From date!", 2).show();
                        txtToDate.setText("Invalid date");

                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        txtToDate.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                    }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please select the valid date!", 2).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Department_Webservice.java asynk class to fill department list**

```
    package com.city.webservices;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import com.city.data.DeptBean;
    import com.city.data.HttpUrl;
    import com.smartcity.CityApplication;

    public class Department_Webservice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        Context contxt;
        InputStream is;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        DeptBean beanlist;
        ArrayList<DeptBean>listDept;
        public String TAG = "Department_Webservice";
        HttpResponse response;
        String str = "";
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        public static String deptNames[],deptId[];
        Spinner spinnerDept;


        public Department_Webservice(Context ctx,ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter,Spinner spinnerDept) {
            this.contxt  = ctx;
            this.dataAdapter  = dataAdapter;
            this.spinnerDept  = spinnerDept;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contxt);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try
            {
                    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(HttpUrl.get_department);

                        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if(response.toString()!=null){

                        JSONArray  jarray = new JSONArray(str);
                        listDept = new ArrayList<DeptBean>();
                        for(int i = 0; i<jarray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            beanlist =  new DeptBean();
                            beanlist.setDeptId(jobj.getString("jobid"));        
                            beanlist.setDeptName(jobj.getString("role"));
                            listDept.add(beanlist);
                        }
                        Log.v(TAG, "listDept size>>>>>>>>>> " + listDept.size());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        } 

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(response.toString()!=null)
            {
                    CityApplication.setDeptBeanlist(listDept);

                        deptNames = new String[listDept.size()];
                        deptId = new String[listDept.size()];
                        for (int i=0; i<listDept.size(); i++)
                        {
                            deptNames[i] = listDept.get(i).getDeptName();
                            deptId[i] = listDept.get(i).getDeptId();
                        }



                        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contxt,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, deptNames);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinnerDept.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            else
            {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(contxt).setTitle("Message").setMessage("Server is not responding." ).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
            }

        }

    }
```

**GetExecutive_Webservices.java asynk class to fill the associated list of executive names**

```
    package com.city.webservices;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    import com.city.data.ExecutiveBean;
    import com.city.data.HttpUrl;

    public class GetExecutive_Webservices extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Context contxt;
        InputStream is;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String deptId;
        public static ArrayList<ExecutiveBean> alist;
        public String TAG = "GetExecutive_Webservices";
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        Spinner spinnerExecutive;
        public static String exceutiveNames[],exceutiveIds[];
        String str = "";
        HttpResponse response;
        public GetExecutive_Webservices(Context ctx, String deptId,
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter, Spinner spinnerExecutive) {
            this.contxt = ctx;
            this.deptId = deptId;
            this.dataAdapter = dataAdapter;
            this.spinnerExecutive = spinnerExecutive;
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contxt);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("department_id", deptId));

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HttpUrl.get_executive);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params1));

                Log.v(TAG, "params1" + params1);

                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

                Log.v(TAG, "str>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + str);


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (response.toString() != null) {

                    alist = new ArrayList<ExecutiveBean>();

                    JSONArray jaray = new JSONArray(str);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jaray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jobj = jaray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ExecutiveBean bean = new ExecutiveBean();
                        bean.setExecutiveId(jobj.getString("id"));
                        bean.setExecutiveName(jobj.getString("username"));
                        alist.add(bean);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Username>>>>>>>>>>" + jobj.getString("username"));

                    }
                    Log.v(TAG, "executive list size>>>>>>>>>>" + alist.size());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (response.toString() != null) {

                exceutiveNames = new String[alist.size()];
                exceutiveIds = new String[alist.size()];
                for (int i=0; i<alist.size(); i++)
                {
                    exceutiveNames[i] = alist.get(i).getExecutiveName();
                    exceutiveIds[i] = alist.get(i).getExecutiveId();
                }



                dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contxt,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, exceutiveNames);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerExecutive.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


            } else {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(contxt)
                        .setTitle("Message")
                        .setMessage("Server is not responding.")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }).create().show();
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "onPostExecute" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Here is HttpUrl.get_department & HttpUrl.get_executive is the url of the method of webservices

   2. DeptBean & ExecutiveBean is the Getter Setter

Hope this post will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Give me sometime to try this n update you